# Mostrar y ocultar botones usando select option con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Requiero hacer un `select option` donde dependiendo de la opción seleccionada, me muestre o me oculte botones.

Por ejemplo: Cuando entro a la vista sólo quiero que me imprima el primer botón, si selecciono la opción 2, que se imprima el segundo botón, pero el primer botón se oculte.

Aquí va lo que estuve usando:

```
<style>
  #hidden_div {
      display: none;
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv(divId, element){
        document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value ==1 ? 'block' : 'none';

    }
</script>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Seleccione una opcion (recomendable probar el monto antes de invertir)</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onchange="showDiv('hidden_div', this)">
            <option value="1">Probar</option>
            <option value="2">Invertir</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 form-group" id="hidden_div">
    <button type="submit" name="btn" value="probar" class="btn btn-primary">Probar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Alberto, bienvenido. Te recomiendo seguir el [tour], para que sepás como formular mejor tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En el HTML hice unos cambios. Los botones tienen la también clase `.btn_1` y `.btn_2`
En el css hago todos los botones `display:none;` y añado una clase `.visible` que tiene `display:inline-block;`.

En el javascript al cambiar la opción seleccionada elimino la clase visible de todos los botones y la añado solo al botón se corresponde con el valor de la opción seleccionada.

```js
//todos los botones
let botones = document.querySelectorAll("button");

//cada vez que el valor del select cambia
exampleFormControlSelect1.addEventListener("change",()=>{
  //recupera el valor de la opción seleccionada
  let valorSeleccionado = exampleFormControlSelect1.options[exampleFormControlSelect1.selectedIndex].value;
  // para todos los botones elimina la clese visible
  botones.forEach(b =>{b.classList.remove("visible")})
  //selecciona el boton que tiene que ser visible
  
  let elBoton = document.querySelector(`.btn_${valorSeleccionado}`)
  //y si el boton existe
  if(elBoton){
  //y le añade la clase visible
  elBoton.classList.add("visible");
  }
})
```

```css
button{display:none;} 
.visible {
      display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right" for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Seleccione una opcion (recomendable probar el monto antes de invertir)</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option value="">----</option>
            <option value="1">Probar</option>
            <option value="2">Invertir</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5 form-group" >
    <button type="submit" name="btn" value="probar" class="btn btn_1">Probar</button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn" value="invertir" class="btn btn_2">invertir</button>
</div>
```

Comment: no me funciono me siguen apareciendo los 2 botones seguramente algo estoy haciendo mal gracias por la respuesta

Comment: En el HTML hice algunos cambios, Para saber por que no funciona necesito ver lo tu código, Por favor ponlo en codepen o jsfiddle y mándame el enlace

Comment: https://codepen.io/broaster123/pen/XwBPvP

Comment: ese es el link del codepen gracias por tu paciencia

Comment: Gracias por el enlace. Esto no me sirve.  Necesitaría ver el HTML resultante. Creo que lo puedes sacar del inspector.

Comment: El código que has pasado en codepen, a mi me funciona, también me funciona el de la respuesta, debe de estar algo mal en tu navegador.